# Android analog signal

Tags: android, kernel, signal-processing, smartphone

Is there any way to record analog signals from a smartphone's Bluetooth, Wifi, or NFC receiver in Android? I'm aware that this will probably not be possible with an Android App using the Android API. However, may this be possible by modifying certain parts in the Android OS Kernel?

Comment: what do you mean, "analog signals". tune in to the BT/wifi/nfc frequencies as if they were an AM/FM broadcast and just "listen"? I highly doubt there's anything in android for this. it'd depend ENTIRELY on very low level hardware details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "linux kernel drivers" for those. 
Source/drivers/bluetooth/ for instance in one of the linux source browsers on the web.
There you might be able to find what signals can be picked up.
But, you probably also want to know the frequency of the analog signal you want to pick-up. I HIGHLY doubt the Wifi hardware will do anything but the 2.4GHz, 5GHz stuff (look up what it is exactly) and similarly for BT. So, you will not be able to get general, spread-spectrum signal monitoring I doubt. So, finally, you must attach your own antenna and convert it to some input. E.g. you could do some rube-g system with a mic wire and then some tuner antenna arrangement perhaps. That would be fairly cheap to do and neat as a signal scanner.